# Apollo DataSource - How to make VSCode Intellisense work with it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, apollo, apollo-server

I'm developing node.js Apollo Server app.

I'm using DataSource class to make queries to database or fetch from other APIs, like this Apollo tutorial project(https://github.com/apollographql/fullstack-tutorial).

Problem is, VSCode intellisense autocompletion is not properly working on this kind of approach. I have to look up DataSource files every time when I can't remember the function name right.

Is there any way I can set up ESLint or Apollo-Graphql extension to make use of intellisense autosuggestion?